Montgomery Powering Ladder for long weierstrass equations
My question is the following:
I know that for elliptic curves in short weierstrass form, I have the following "one-coordinate addition" formula:
Let $P = (x_p,y_p), Q = (x_q, y_q)$. If I am additionally given the $x$-coordinate of $P-Q$, say $x_{P-Q}$, then we have the following formula for the $x$-coordinate for $P+Q$:
$$x_{P+Q} = \dfrac{2\left(x_{P} + x_{Q}\right)\left(x_{P}x_{Q} + A\right) + 4B}{\left(x_{P} - x_{Q}\right)^{2}} - x_{P-Q}$$
where $A,B$ are the coefficents of the curve in Weierstrass form (i.e. $y^2 = x^3+Ax+B$).
Now for my question: can something similiar be done for a long weierstrass equation, i.e. $E: y^2 +a_1xy + a_3y = x^3+a_2x^2+a_4x + a_6$?

See the original paper The Montgomery Powering Ladder by Marc Joye and Sung-Ming Yen

I recommend you reading section 3.4 on Montgomery curves and their arithmetic by Craig Costello and Benjamin Smith.
Given a general Weierstrass model \begin{equation*} \mathcal{E}:y^2 = x^3+f_2x^2+f_1x+f_0\end{equation*}
The analogue for "pseudo-addition" is \begin{equation*}x_{P+Q} x_{P-Q}(x_P-x_Q)^2 = (x_Px_Q-f_1)^2-4f_0(x_P+x_Q+f_2)\end{equation*} and for "pseudo-doubling" is
\begin{equation*}4x_{[2]P}(x^3_P+f_2x^2_P+f_1x_P+f_0) = (x^2_P-f_1)^2 - 4f_0(2x_P+f_2)\end{equation*}
In the cited document, you can also find the respective formulas in projective coordinates.

Thanks for the answer! However, I was thinking about a long Weierstrass equation of the form $E : y^2 +a_1xy+a_3y = x^3+a_2x² + a_4x + a_6$. The main problem I am struggling with is the mixed term $a_1xy$ which doesn't generalize nicely from the formulas given by you/the paper. Is there a trick for this, too?

Something that maybe could help is that, assuming that the characteristic of the field is not 2, one can obtain the "general" Weierstrass model above from the long Weierstrass equation by the substitution $y \to y-(a_1x+a_3)/2$.

i know, however, i wanted to find something for general characteristic, especially 2 and 3  :)
